# R/Bioconductor query for a gene?

Tags: bioinformatics, gene

I'm fairly new to bioinformatics, so please be gentle ;0

Is there a way to query a particular gene using a script in R/Bioconductor? I'm particularly interested in Gene Ontology terms. There are many websites that, given the gene name, will return relevant GO terms. My question is, can it be automated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please ask questions about *Bioconductor* on the *Bioconductor* [support site](https://support.bioconductor.org).

Bioconductor also distributes ['annotation' packages](http://bioconductor.org/packages/release/BiocViews.html#___AnnotationData) with curated information. These don't rely on a web service, so are always available, and are fixed at each (6 month) Bioconductor release, but are less comprehensive. Choose your organism

```
BiocInstaller::biocLite(c("org.Hs.eg.db", "GO.db"))  # first time only
library("org.Hs.eg.db"); library("GO.db")
```

Query for GO ids

```
symbols = c("BRCA1", "BRCA2")
df = select(org.Hs.eg.db, symbols, columns="GO", keytype="SYMBOL")
```

Symbol - GO mappings are 1:many, so

```
> dim(df)
[1] 149   4
> head(df)
  SYMBOL         GO EVIDENCE ONTOLOGY
1  BRCA1 GO:0000151      NAS       CC
2  BRCA1 GO:0000724      IDA       BP
3  BRCA1 GO:0000724      TAS       BP
4  BRCA1 GO:0000794      IEA       CC
5  BRCA1 GO:0003677      TAS       MF
6  BRCA1 GO:0003682      IEA       MF
```

Use the GO.db package to gain more insight into the GO ids

```
> head(select(GO.db, df$GO, "TERM"))
'select()' returned many:1 mapping between keys and columns
        GOID                                                    TERM
1 GO:0000151                                ubiquitin ligase complex
2 GO:0000724 double-strand break repair via homologous recombination
3 GO:0000724 double-strand break repair via homologous recombination
4 GO:0000794                            condensed nuclear chromosome
5 GO:0003677                                             DNA binding
6 GO:0003682                                       chromatin binding
```

See the vignettes on the [AnnotationDbi](https://bioconductor.org/packages/AnnotationDbi) landing page, the annotation-related [work flows](http://bioconductor.org/help/workflows/), and the [training material](http://bioconductor.org/help/course-materials/) on the Bioconductor web site.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [biomaRt](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/biomaRt.html) package. This package allows you to access some databases in R directly. Quote from the user's guide:

> The package enables retrieval of large amounts of data
>   in a uniform way without the need to know the underlying database schemas
>   or write complex SQL queries. Examples of BioMart databases are Ensembl,
>   Uniprot  and  HapMap.   These  major  databases  give  biomaRt  users  direct
>   access to a diverse set of data and enable a wide range of powerful online
>   queries from R.

In the [user's guide](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/biomaRt/inst/doc/biomaRt.pdf) you will find anything you need, i.e. description and example tasks, for doing queries on HGNC symbols, GO terms, and more.